# Android CDC ACM as device

Tags: android, usb, device, cdc

I have to make my application communicate with an USB device.
This device can only use CDC ACM as "host". So, if I'm right, I have to be "device".

I have no clue how to implement that. I searched for a long time and I found a lot of way to communicate as "host" but I have not found how to do it as device.

Someone have a sample of code or a link to a tuto?

Best regards,
ATA Dev

Comment: Is the Host device something that is compatible with the Android Device? The Host device would have to know how to communicate, and that usually means device drivers or generic standard protocols (USB Mass Storage, Serial Communications, etc.)

Comment: The host have the [HCC USB Host Stack](http://www.hcc-embedded.com/embedded-systems-software-products/embedded-usb-driver/software-host-class-driver) included with "CDC ACM" host class

Answer (score 1):

Android can certainly communicate with CDC ACM devices and act as one as well. Have a look at https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android this library and look at the class `CdcAcmSerialDriver.java` where they have implemented the driver for Android for CDC ACM devices.

Comment: By my test, the library do recognize CdcAcmSerialDriver. All connect/open process return ok but I cannot receive any data from the device.

Comment: Have you asked and been granted permission to access USB peripherals?

Answer (score -1):

**This question concerns Android operating as a USB *device*, hence it is fundamentally distinct from the more common case of Android operating as a USB *host* using the Android USB APIs**

In terms of the specific requirement to be a CDC ACM device, Android device hardware should be able to support a CDC ACM implementation, however Android itself normally does not, and the security model of production user builds means that this is not something that can be added by an application.

Rather, you would need to modify the Android installation, likely at kernel level, to cause it to implement this USB mode instead or in addition to the usual ones.  The first step would be finding out if you can practically change the Android installation on your device at all, and the second would be finding if it uses a "gadget" based USB framework or one of the other approaches that has been used from time to time.

Another option could be to find a microcontroller with two USB peripherals and configure it to be a "bridge" between Android and your particular host device.  Or you could use something with one USB interface to talk to that, and a bluetooth or wifi radio to talk to the Android device.

Comment: What would be an example of a bridge peripheral?

Comment: @dazza5000 you misread, "a microcontroller with two USB peripherals" ie, the USB engines would be on-chip *peripherals of the MCU*.  Part selections questions are off topic, so use a manufacturer selection matrix to find a suitable chip in a series you personally feel like working with - I know there as some STM32F4xx parts with two.  Needless to say this would be a fairly advanced firmware project.